# Deploy opencv+cuda function on the existed KCF tracker in python

Tags: python-3.x, opencv, image-processing, deep-learning

I'm working on an object tracking project for which i'm using KCF tracker provided in opencv

```
tracker = cv2.TrackerKCF_create()
ret,bbox_red = tracker.update(frame)
```

I profiled my code and found out that the update method is the one that requires the longest processing time in every call (3.2 sec), besides other used methods which also require long processing time. So I'm trying to optimize that by exploiting my Nvidia 1070-8GB GPU card, since i built opencv with cuda and cudnn.

So is there a method like `cv2.cuda.TrackerKCF_create()` or `cv2.cuda.Videocapture()` ? and where can i find the whole opencv+cuda methods?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Check out the documentation of [OpenCV CUDA APIs](https://docs.opencv.org/master/d1/d1e/group__cuda.html). [cudacodec](https://docs.opencv.org/master/d0/d61/group__cudacodec.html) seems like one of the ones you are looking for. Also check out [implementation of a GPU version of the KCF algorithm](https://denismerigoux.github.io/GPU-tracking/).

Comment: @Burak. Thanks dude!. However, the second link seems to be exactly what i'm looking for but i didnt find the code. I mean the method!

Comment: [The code](https://github.com/denismerigoux/GPU-tracking/tree/master/src) is written in C++ and seems to be not very systematic. Unfortunately, the rest is up to you.